# Mac application crashes (killed due to entitlements) regardless of whether entitlements are enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, entitlements

I have an application that has iCloud enabled in the Entitlements file, but doesn't actually make use of the feature. (Just getting my ducks in a row so I can switch on the functionality in the future.)

My application was launching fine, but yesterday it suddenly stopped launching. I was able to determine from the Console that the app was being killed due:

```
1/6/12 7:25:17.433 AM taskgated: killed com.xxx.xxx[pid 14991] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed
```

I found this strange, since my App ID and provisioning profile have been configured w/ iCloud for a long while now, and iCloud has been actively used in development versions for testing.

Anyway, to test a few unrelated features I *disabled entitlements* for the application, deselecting the "Enable Entitlements" checkbox in the project editor:

[image: Entitlements Disabled]

But, even after cleaning and relaunching, the application is **killed in the same way.** I have also tried launching with *entitlements enabled, but with the iCloud Containers all deleted.* No luck.

Comment: Any news?  Having this same problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812747/taskgated-killed-app-because-its-use-of-the-com-apple-developer-ubiquity-contai

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm still completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, deleting the provisioning profile I created to access iCloud helped (besides of cleaning, trashing Container & derived data) - lot of trial & error.